# Php Transform string to float adds decimal places

Tags: php, string, transform, rounding, currency

I was wondering why this happens because it seems very odd to me. 
In a form a price is submitted looks like this `1.188,00 €` (this in an example!)

with the original data from the form, the transformations the result is `1188.008364`

```
$colorP = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $value['_gravity_form_lead']['92.2'])); 
$colorP = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $colorP);
$colorP = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/ui','',$colorP);

echo $colorP; // result-> 1188.008364
```

Where are the additional decimal digits coming from? 
Quite sure this can be transformed differently so I'm open for suggestions.

Many thanks for the answers

Comment: You're missing an `)` on the first line so the code won't run, after adding the code runs perfectly for me.

Comment: Sorry, was a copy/paste error. Changed it with a little better explanation

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the additional decimal digits is that the transformation results in a `float` and that is not very precise. 
[PHP Float description](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)